# How to run all the component at once in choice parameters in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, devops

Here i am using two choice parameter one is Branch and other is Component, Here i am able to run specific component but i need to run all the component at once?

```
1.Choices Parameter

Name:   Branch
choices:trunk
        branch/3.2.0

2.Choice Parameter:

Name:   Component
Choices:loadbalance 
        alert
        generic-report
        backend-tool
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare 4 stages, each one with the second parameter *already* set (meaning not part of your parameters), and called using [the **`parallel`** syntax](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/09/25/declarative-1/)

That way:

- you don't have to deal with an "extended choice parameter"
- you can differentiate each stage
- you can run them in parallel

Comment: In this case i was able to use extended choice parameters. But i am using Poll with a URL in build trigger https://url.com/${Component}/${Branch}. here i am giving input. if i am select two components it takes both. for eg: https://url.com/loadbalance, alert/${Branch}, but it should pass one by one.

Comment: @user11668570 OK, but you had selected the right answer for your question at the time. Why unselect it?

Comment: @ oh sorry my mistake. In my case it will not work in pipeline.

Comment: @user11668570 because you have to enter an input?

Comment: is it possible to do it in freestyle job itself with the help of plugins?

Comment: @user11668570 same answer than the one you selected: make a first freestyle job where you select/enter your inputs. Then chain it to another job which will use those parameters, without having to stop and demand new input.